# Unable to add controller in MVC Core 1.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to add a new controller in my project but it is disabled. I can't add it. Is there any work around?
Reinstalling  .net core sdk again shows the following.

---

> The following error occurred attempting to run the project model
>   server process (1.0.0-preview2-003121).
>
> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:3985
>
> The project model server process provides intellisense, build, and
>   reference information to Visual Studio and without it your experience
>   will be very limited. Please try closing and reopening Visual Studio
>   to see if that corrects the problem. Alternatively, check that the
>   .NET Core SDK is properly installed.

---

[image]

Comment: First Check is your project running in Debug Mode?

Comment: No.it's not.I have tried many times  by creating different projects but no success

Comment: Check your if visual studio is up to date and project settings are correct for the type of the project. I had issues like that with navigate to view/controller earlier. When my visual studio was older.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I start a new .NET core project.

1.Update vs2015

2.Reinstall Core SDK

3.In global.json delete version, for example

```
{
    "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
    "sdk": {   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue come up. I found a work-around, it's very odd but it does work. Close visual studio, open your project directory in command prompt & type **dotnet run**. Let it finish doing it's thing. Close out command prompt & re-open the solution in visual studio. This cleared up the error. I have to do this every time I want to work with a project. I know this doesn't explain the why, but hope that helps.